# i dont understand how to use TextureLoader its drop the IO EXCEPTION

Tags: java, image, exception

hello guys i just wrote code in java3d (SimpleUniverse) i don't understand  the Exception that it drops to me and why it cant read the file... i tried to put image as my backGround image via TextureLoader thanks for any help guys.
this is the  exception:

> com.sun.j3d.utils.image.ImageException: javax.imageio.IIOException:
>   Can't read input file! at
>   com.sun.j3d.utils.image.TextureLoader$1.run(TextureLoader.java:344) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   com.sun.j3d.utils.image.TextureLoader.(TextureLoader.java:337)
>   at
>   com.sun.j3d.utils.image.TextureLoader.(TextureLoader.java:291)
>   at Aplication.backGround.createSceneGraph(backGround.java:60) at
>   Aplication.backGround.(backGround.java:39) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file! at
>   javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sun.j3d.utils.image.TextureLoader$1.run(TextureLoader.java:342)
>   ... 14 more

here is the code:

/*====================================================================*/

```
package Aplication;

import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;

import java.applet.Applet;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;

import javax.media.j3d.AmbientLight;
import javax.media.j3d.Background;
import javax.media.j3d.BoundingSphere;
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;
import javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D;
import javax.media.j3d.DirectionalLight;

    import javax.media.j3d.ImageComponent2D;
    import javax.media.j3d.Shape3D;
    import javax.media.j3d.TransformGroup;

import javax.vecmath.Point3d;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3f;

import com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.image.TextureLoader;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;

public class backGround extends Applet{
    private java.net.URL bgImage = null;

    public backGround(){
        init();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        GraphicsConfiguration config =
                SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();

        Canvas3D c = new Canvas3D(config);
        add("Center", c);

        BranchGroup scene = createSceneGraph();
        SimpleUniverse u = new SimpleUniverse(c);

        // This will move the ViewPlatform back a bit so the
        // objects in the scene can be viewed.
        u.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        scene.compile();

        u.addBranchGraph(scene);

    }
    public void init(){
        setSize(1280,650);

    }

    public BranchGroup createSceneGraph(){
        BranchGroup firstBranch = new BranchGroup();
        //background.setColor(0.0f,0.0f,2.0f);
        BoundingSphere backgroundBounds = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0,0,0), 1000);

        TextureLoader myLoader = new  TextureLoader("../images/sky.jpg",this);
        ImageComponent2D myImage = myLoader.getImage( );
        Background background = new Background();
        background.setImage(myImage);
        background.setApplicationBounds(backgroundBounds);
        firstBranch.addChild(background);

        Shape3D plane = new createPlane().getGeo();
        plane.setBounds(new BoundingSphere());
        firstBranch.addChild(plane);

        AmbientLight lightA = new AmbientLight();
        lightA.setInfluencingBounds(new BoundingSphere());
        firstBranch.addChild(lightA);

        DirectionalLight lightD1 = new DirectionalLight();
        lightD1.setInfluencingBounds(new BoundingSphere());
        Vector3f direction = new Vector3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        direction.normalize();
        lightD1.setDirection(direction);
        firstBranch.addChild(lightD1);

        return firstBranch;
    }




public static void main(String argv[]) {
    Frame frame = new MainFrame(new backGround(), 750, 750);
  }
}
```

/*===============plane Class that is necessary to run the code above====== */

```
package Aplication;

import javax.media.j3d.Appearance;
import javax.media.j3d.Geometry;
import javax.media.j3d.GeometryArray;
import javax.media.j3d.Material;
import javax.media.j3d.QuadArray;
import javax.media.j3d.Shape3D;
import javax.vecmath.Color3f;
import javax.vecmath.Point3f;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3f;


public class createPlane extends Shape3D {
    Shape3D plane;
      public class LitQuad extends Shape3D {
            LitQuad(Point3f A, Point3f B, Point3f C, Point3f D) {
              this.setGeometry(createGeometry(A, B, C, D));
              this.setAppearance(createAppearance());
            }


      Geometry createGeometry(Point3f A, Point3f B, Point3f C, Point3f D) {

          QuadArray plane = new QuadArray(4, GeometryArray.COORDINATES
              | GeometryArray.NORMALS);

          plane.setCoordinate(0, A);
          plane.setCoordinate(1, B);
          plane.setCoordinate(2, C);
          plane.setCoordinate(3, D);

          Vector3f a = new Vector3f(A.x - B.x, A.y - B.y, A.z - B.z);
          Vector3f b = new Vector3f(C.x - B.x, C.y - B.y, C.z - B.z);
          Vector3f n = new Vector3f();
          n.cross(b, a);

          n.normalize();

          plane.setNormal(0, n);
          plane.setNormal(1, n);
          plane.setNormal(2, n);
          plane.setNormal(3, n);

          return plane;
        }

       Appearance createAppearance() {
          Appearance appear = new Appearance();
          Color3f color = new Color3f(0.0f,1.5f,0.0f);
          Material material = new Material();
          material.setDiffuseColor(color);
          appear.setMaterial(material);

          return appear;
        }
      }

      public createPlane(){
            plane = new LitQuad(new Point3f(-1.5f, -0.5f, -5.0f),
                    new Point3f(-1.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f),
                    new Point3f(1.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f), new Point3f(1.5f, -0.5f, -5.0f));
      }
      public Shape3D getGeo(){
          return plane;
      }
}
```

Comment: "if you want me to put the code here" <-- yes; that is pretty much mandatory. Exceptions without code is equally as uninformative as code without exceptions (if the code raises an error, that is)

Comment: just updated the question with the code that needed the code contain 2 classes. @fge thanks for helping

Comment: @lxg here are the changes

Comment: @Unheilig here the changes

Comment: @lan here the changes